# Floating point exception when storing something into unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I'm using `unordered_map` as a hashmap in C++, but whenever I try to store anything in there, I get:

`Floating point exception: 8`

Can anyone point out what the error is? The following is how I initialized my map (`table_entry` is just a struct):

`std::tr1::unordered_map<unsigned short, table_entry*> forwarding_table;`

Then I was putting an entry in by doing:

```
unsigned short dest_id = 0;    
table_entry *entry = (table_entry *)malloc(sizeof(table_entry));   
forwarding_table[dest_id] = entry;
```

My struct's definition is:

```
typedef struct table_entry {
    unsigned short next_hop;
    unsigned int cost;
} table_entry;
```

In terms of my compiler version, when I run `g++ -v` I get this:

`Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1`

Comment: If `table_entry` isn't a POD type, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Just looked up what POD type is and I believe it is. I'll add my struct definition in just for clarity.

Comment: @chris, just storing a pointer should be fine no matter what bad things might happen when you try to use it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Still, is there any particular advantage over just using (in order of best to worst) a normal object, smart pointer, or `new`?

Comment: Running your program under a debugger might give you a more precise idea of which operation is causing the problem.

Comment: I put in a bunch of print statements and narrowed the problem down to the line of the assignment (`forwarding_table[dest_id] = entry;`).

Comment: @chris those are all good suggestions. I was just pointing out that your observation was unlikely to be the source of the particular symptom prompting the question.

Comment: What's your compiler? This worked fine for me:
//g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 tryhashmap.cc -o tryhashmap
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct table_entry {
    unsigned short next_hop;
    unsigned int cost;
} table_entry;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<unsigned short, table_entry*> forwarding_table;
    unsigned short dest_id = 0;
    table_entry *entry = (table_entry *)malloc(sizeof(table_entry));
    entry->next_hop = 42;
    forwarding_table[dest_id] = entry;
    std::cout << forwarding_table[dest_id]->next_hop << std::endl;
}

Comment: Oooh is my compiler version too old? I've edited the post with my compiler version. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered the same problem using a variety of instantiations of `std::unordered_map<>`.  However, I can only reproduce the problem when the map is global to a shared object.  If the map is declared as a global in the program, or as a local within a function, then the problem does not manifest.

(Note: I'm using GCC 4.9.4, 32-bit mode, with -std=c++11)

It appears that allocating the `std::unordered_map<>` on the heap solves my problem.  Maybe it would solve yours?  Consider replacing:

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<unsigned short, table_entry*> forwarding_table;
```

with

```
std::tr1::unordered_map<unsigned short, table_entry*>* forwarding_table;
```

And then updating uses of `forwarding_table` appropriately.

Comment: A little more googling reveals another workaround:  Inserting a reserve() call before first use seems to solve the problem.  See [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61143)

Comment: For me only this solution with allocating on the heap worked properly. The reserve() trick failed quite badly past inserting more than 20 entries.

Comment: When you are putting it in heap, you are calling `new` explicitly, thereby the map is getting constructed properly, and thus the issue is gone. Please check how you initialize it when you put in `struct`,  I think there is improper `malloc` somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is invalid initialization. We cannot use "malloc" in C++ standard library initialization, because malloc does not "construct" the object.

In C++ an object contains virtual table and these virtual tables are not created by "malloc/memset".

Comment: True but irrelevant, it doesn't cause this problem.

Comment: @user207421 I had the same issue. In my case the issue was that map was not constructed. Even if you put the map in a `struct` or shared memory, that does not guarantee the proper initialization when the owner is allocated by `malloc`.